# Find the value of $f(t)$ for which $f ' (t) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$f(t) = 8t^{1/2} + 6t^{-1/2}$$

Somehow I think the question is related to the previous parts, where I did:

> a) Find an expression for $f'(t)$.

$f'(t) = 4t^{-1/2} - 3t^{-3/2}$

> b) Find the value for $t$ for which $f'(t) = 0$.

$t = 3/4$

Comment: You've already solved it then?

Comment: So what is the actual answer, then? Would I just say that f(t) = 3/4? Is that what the question is asking?

Comment: What should $t$ be if $f'(t) = 0$? (see b) And what is the function value of $f$ for that value of $t$?

Comment: @TMM: Thanks, that helped me understand what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing left is to find
$$
f\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) = 8\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{1/2} + 6\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1/2} = \dots
$$

Answer (score 2):

You already solved it:

$$f'(t)=\frac{4}{t^{1/2}}-\frac{3}{t\cdot t^{1/2}}=0\Longleftrightarrow 4t-3=0\,\,,\,\,so...$$

Comment: @Thomas: But let him think what should he do next?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Ok